# Why is a surface of revolution injective?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be smooth functions where $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open set such that $f(x) > 0$ and $f'(x)^2 + g'(x)^2 = 1$ for any $x$ in $U$. Consider now the surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $\sigma(u,v) = (f(u)cos(v),f(u)sin(v),g(u))$ where $u \in U$ and $0 < v < 2\pi$.

By the definition of a surface, $\sigma(u,v)$ must be a smooth injective map. I'm wondering why $\sigma$ is injective. Couldn't I take two different couples $(u_1, v_1)$ and $(u_2,v_2)$ such that $\sigma(u_1,v_1) = \sigma(u_2,v_2)$?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think this is talking about the sets of points $\{u, v\}$--whatever "thing" generates these values must be smooth and injective (because we shouldn't visit the same place twice).  I'm not totally sure though.

Comment: Let $u_1, v_1, u_2, v_2$ be appropriate elements such that $\sigma(u_1,v_1) = \sigma(u_2,v_2)$. Then $$f(u_1)\cos(v_1)=f(u_2)\cos(v_2),$$
$$f(u_1)\sin(v_1)=f(u_2)\sin(v_2).$$

Squaring each term and summing top and bottom yields $$(f(u_1))^2\left((\cos(v_1))^2+(\sin(v_1))^2\right)=(f(u_2))^2\left((\cos(v_2))^2+(\sin(v_2))^2\right).$$

Proceed.

Comment: @GitGud I see how this would prove injectivity given that $f$ and $g$ would be injective functions. However, this is not stated. Should this be added in the definition of a surface of revolution?

Comment: Yes. It would be good if you wrote out everything in answer yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypotheses as written *do not imply injectivity*; the "profile" curve $\gamma:U \to \mathbf{R}^{3}$ defined by $\gamma(u) = \bigl(f(u), 0, g(u)\bigr)$ could fail to be injective.

If $\gamma$ *is* injective, however, then $\sigma$ is injective; here's a sketch:

If $v$ is a real number, let $H_{v}$ denote the "longitudinal open half-plane" making an angle $v$ with the "positive $(x, z)$ half-plane":
$$
H_{v} = \{(r\cos v, r\sin v, z) : \text{$r > 0$ and $z$ real}\}.
$$

Now show that:

- For all $(u, v)$ in $U \times (0, 2\pi)$, the point $\sigma(u, v)$ lies in $H_{v}$.
- If $v_{1} \neq v_{2}$ are real numbers in $(0, 2\pi)$, then $H_{v_{1}} \cap H_{v_{2}} = \emptyset$.
- For each $v$ in $(0, 2\pi)$, the curve $u \mapsto \sigma(u, v)$ traces the image of $\gamma$ (a curve in $H_{0}$) rotated through an angle $v$ about the $z$-axis. This curve is injective because $\gamma$ is injective.